# How to work with JSON in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

My Python Script gives a JSON output. How can I see it in the proper JSON format?

I tried with parsing with json.dumps() and json.loads(), but could not achieve the desired result.

======= Myscript.py ========

```
import sys
import jenkins
import json
import credentials

# Credentails 
username = credentials.login['username']
password = credentials.login['password']


# Print the number of jobs present in jenkins
server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', username=username, password=password)


# Get the installed Plugin info
plugins = server.get_plugins_info()
#parsed = json.loads(plugins)   # take a string as input and returns a dictionary as output.
parsed = json.dumps(plugins)    # take a dictionary as input and returns a string as output.
#print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
print(plugins)
print(parsed)
```

Comment: So tell us… what is the desired output and how does it differ from the actual output?

Comment: @Hermann, [Actual Output](https://github.com/bikranz4u/stackoverflow-log/blob/master/actual-output.txt)  [Expected Output](https://github.com/bikranz4u/stackoverflow-log/blob/master/expected-output.txt)

Comment: @Theophrastus, If using json.loads() then getting error      ` testuser at python-jenkins]-py jenkins-plugins.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jenkins-plugins.py", line 17, in <module>
    parsed = json.loads(plugins)   # take a string as input and returns a dictionary as output.
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list`

Comment: @Theophrastus, If json.dumps() used, I am getting the proper JSON output. But I am looking for json with proper readability, [Like](https://github.com/bikranz4u/stackoverflow-log/blob/master/expected-output.txt)

Comment: I fail to see the difference between "proper JSON" and "readable JSON". According to [the documentation](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.get_plugins_info), `get_plugins_info()` already is a python list of dictionaries. There is no need to parse it again. I have no idea why JSON is even mentioned. The dictionaries are probably "fit to be dumped via `json.dumps()`" Also, the documentation urges you to use the newer `get_plugins()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to pretty-print your JSON.  You would need to pass the correct parameters to `json.dumps()`:

`parsed = json.dumps(plugins, sort_keys=True, indent=4)`

Check and see if that is what you are looking for.